# "Model object has no attribute 'save'"

Tags: django

Don't know what to do with this error. How to add data in SQL from forms using post method?

models.py

```
class Lala(models.Model):
    PRIORITY_CHOICES = ( 
        (0, '1'),
        (1, '2'),
        (2, '3'),
        (3, '4'),
     )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateField()
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
```

Views.py

```
def add (request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = AddLala(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            newform = form.save()
```

Form.py

```
class AddLala(forms.Form):
    PRIORITY_CHOICES = ( 
        (0, '1'),
        (1, '2'),
        (2, '3'),
        (3, '4'),
     )
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = forms.DateField()
    priority = forms.CharField(max_length=1, widget=forms.Select(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES))
```

add.html

```
<form target="upload_frame" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit">
</form>
```

urls.py

```
  (r'^add/$', 'QA.QAtool.views.add'),
   (r'^addLala/$', 'QA.QAtool.views.addLala'),
```

So, I can Add data to DB, if I go next way - Just add

```
 lala = Lala(id=None, name='teststep3', date='1943-12-12', priority='High') 
 lala.save()
```

I really don't understand whats wrong, everywhere I see form.save() as a Standard method, but not for me.

Comment: Did you really mean to construct an `AddTest` in the view?

Comment: there is no form action  ...action='/add'

Comment: @mossplix: Irrelevant. Checking the method means that a separate URL isn't required.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, the Django forms.Form *doesn't*  have a save() method - only ModelForm instances have that.  Which is logical - what's it supposed to save and where?

Comment: yes, this all - urls and form action - I missed, thanks

Comment: So How to save a modelForm with values that i input?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try using a ModelForm instead of a Form:

```
class Lala(models.Model):
    PRIORITY_CHOICES = ( 
        (0, '1'),
        (1, '2'),
        (2, '3'),
        (3, '4'),
     )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateField()
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
```

In forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class LalaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lala
```

Then in the view your existing code should (pretty much) cover it:

```
def add (request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = LalaForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()    # saves a new 'Lala' object to the DB
```

Check out the docs for ModelForm [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: Great it realy helps, how can I mmissed it. Another question for now - nothing happens when I press Upload button. "Waiting for localhost" only this, there are no informaion on the screen, only output that I have in a console: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:52: UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestCon

Comment: @user474092 - Might want to open a new question for that.  Looks like you need to put a csrf token in your request context, as shown [in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it).