# Django file upload: Upload form has no save method

Tags: python, django

I got the following situation:

forms.py

```
class DocumentUploadForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(
        validators=[validate_file_extension],
        required=True
    )
    author = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['file', 'author']
```

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    imported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = DocumentUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        # author = request.POST.get('author', None)
        # if author is None:
        #     return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        # document = Document(file=request.FILES['file'], author=author)
        # document.save()
        form.save() # no save() method !!
```

Error: `'DocumentUploadForm' object has no attribute 'save'`

I don't like the way by creating a `document` object by my self and fill in all the necessary information. This leads to a lot of error handling that I don't want to have. So I had a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model

They describe the exact way I implemented but I don't know why I get the AttributeError.

Any help would be nice!
aronadaal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form seems to be mixing `Form` and `ModelForm` code, while inheriting from the basic `Form (forms.Form)`. AFAIK, the basic Django `Form` doesn't have a `save()` method. To use a simple `form.save()`, use ModelForms. You're using class Meta already, so you should be able to just inherit from ModelForm and remove the first two lines of your form:

```
class DocumentUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['file', 'author']
```

See ModelForm docs for more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/
and also the answers to this question: [object has no attribute 'save' Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271686/object-has-no-attribute-save-django)