# object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django

'EmailPostForm' object has no attribute 'save'
**My views**

```
def post_share( request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/')
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', {'form': form})
```

**Forms**

```
class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    comments = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
    specialization = forms.CharField()
```

he gives me 'EmailPostForm' object has no attribute 'save' pls help me

Comment: Only ModelForms have a save method, plain forms don't. Is there a model class involved here? If so why aren't you isn't a modelform?

Comment: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) This can help you understand your's mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object has no attribute 'save' Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271686/object-has-no-attribute-save-django)

Answer (score 0):

watch out your `'Forms.py'`

```
class EmailPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

remember, only the `'Form'` inherits from `'forms.ModelForm'` has the attribute `'save'`

Answer (score -1):

This won't work:

```
class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
```

Instead, try this way:

```
class EmailPostForm(forms.Model.Form):
```

As there is no save for Model if you want to use save you have to use Model.Form.